# Load balancing based on Content

Tags: load-balancing

I wanted to send all the requests for same content to the same backend server. How I can do this. Are there any open source versions like HaProxy which can do this.

For example. Client 1 has requested for Content A, and my load balancer directs that request to one of the backend server say X on round robin basis. Now if I receive a request from different client 2 for the same content A, this request should be directed to the same backend server X. Are there any open source solution which can do this.

Any help/pointers would be appreciated.

Thanks, Nikhil

Answer (score 2):

`Ha proxy` can do what you want and more. It has many `acl options` available to suit most requirements. `Varnish` is another option that has a robust acl language.

Answer (score 0):

Interesting question! 
I'm affraid it can depend on technology. As long as you're in HTTP domain, maybe you can somehow configure your loadbalancer.

I'm a Java guy, so, in java you can have, say EJB. These are distributed components installed on server and can be run remotely. Their communication protocol is binary and I doubt load balancer can read it.

So, in JBoss, for example you can create a cluster of servers, and deploy different EJBs on different servers.
For example, lets assume, there are two EJBs in the system. One allows to buy milk, and one for pizza.

So you deploy the milk ejb on server 1 and pizza ejb on server 2.

Now you have a naming resolution service (in java/jboss its called HA-JNDI).
It basic idea is to provide a remote stub based on the name:

```
PizzaEJB pizzaEjb = NamingService.getMyStub(PizzaEJB.class);
```

Its not a real working code of course, but it demonstrates an idea.

The trick is that this naming server knows where each EJB is deployed, so if you have the pizza ejb only on server 2 it will always return a stub that will go to server 2 and buy the pizza :)

Java programmers so, don't really care how its implemented under the hood. Just to give an idea - the naming service has some form of agent deployed on each server and they talk with each other...

This is how java can work here.

Now what I think, maybe you can base your api on Restful web services, in this case its easily parsable http request, so the implementation can be relatively easy (again, if your load balancer supports this kind of processing).

Hope this helps somehow

Comment: Thanks for your thought Mark, but I have not decided which load balancer should I use. Yes the requests are HTTP request which I need to route to one of the backend servers (Apache)